# How to tag a certain changeset in Git?

Tags: git, tagging

I am trying to find out how to tag a changeset that occurred earlier in the history. I am doing this as a feature part of a program, so, I can't do checkout and then tag, because the working copy may not be clean, and I dare not to modify the stash either because it may already contain something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the man:

```
git tag <tagname> <commit>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use:

```
git tag tag_name commit_hash
```

More on tags: [Git tags](http://book.git-scm.com/3_git_tag.html) in the *Git Community Book*.